# How to analysis python performance and view results as call tree?

Tags: python, line-profiler

I have seen such a program in accident, but I forget the name and can not find it anymore.

It works just like line profiler. Well, when I saw it, it's an article comparing it with line profiler. The results are more friendly. They are like

```
main               100%
    -fun1          95%
        -subfun1   80%
        ...
    -fun2          5%
        -subfun1   4%
        ...
```

By result like this, I can know where subfun1 is called most.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can you get the call tree with python profilers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544784/how-can-you-get-the-call-tree-with-python-profilers)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the python default profiler and the module Snakeviz for a nice visual representation.