# use PyCharm to view profiling data

Tags: pycharm, cprofile

Does anyone know if there is a way to open external .pstat files inside PyCharm for viewing?  When I try to, I'm being asked to select the file type, but there doesn't seem to be the option for it (even those the view is used for internally generated profile data).

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's also under Tools->Open cProfile Snapshot

Comment: and yes it is only available in the PyCharm Professional (non-free) edition.

Answer (score 7):

Since PyCharm 2017, the profiler plugin is available only in the Professional (non-free) edition of PyCharm, and not in the Community (free & open-source) edition.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

- goto settings->Keymap->Plug-ins->Python Profiler->Open Cprofile Snapshot
- assign some shortcut to this action
- try to run this shortcut and open pstat file

Comment: I don't find the python profiler. Is it that it has been removed for PyCharm community edition. Can we not add that library from the python interpreter? if yes what is the name of the library?