# I cannot find profile button in Pycharm Community 2020.2 in CentOS

Tags: python, pycharm

As the following figure shows, there is not a `profile` button under `run` buttom.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
import time

def fun1():
    time.sleep(1)

def fun2():
    time.sleep(1)

def fun3():
    time.sleep(2)

def fun4():
    time.sleep(1)

def fun5():
    time.sleep(1)
    fun4()

fun1()
fun2()
fun3()
fun5()
```

My Pycharm version is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the profiler plugin is in the Professional (non-free) edition of PyCharm, you can test it out in professional edition

Comment: Is it available for Edutation Edition?

Comment: don't know  about that but manually you can do it , [it may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926847/profiling-a-python-program-with-pycharm-or-any-other-ide), you can try professional edition f or 30 days trial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Profiler is supported only in PyCharm Professional, see https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html