# Document Python function objects as calls in Doxygen

Tags: python, doxygen, graphviz

I'm looking to create doxygen documentation for my code that includes dot graphs for function calls, but I want it to include possible function calls that are called from function objects. For example:

```
def main():
    funcall(Test)
    funcall(TestTwo)

def funcall(obj):
    obj()

def Test():
    print('Test')

def TestTwo():
    print('Test two')
```

I'd like to have a dot graph that shows a connection from main->funcall, and from funcall->Test and funcall->TestTwo. It doesn't need to be automated, if there's a way to just tell doxygen that these are existing connections and should be shown on the call graph in a cleaner way than adding `if(0): Test()`. Is this possible?

Comment: This code doesn't actually work; you'll get a TypeError, because you're trying to call a string like a function.

Comment: Missed that, thanks. Fixed (and ran it this time just to make sure the MWE actually works)

Comment: Your approach is limited by the attempt to do the work statically. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544784/how-can-you-get-the-call-tree-with-python-profilers#23164271) for a dynamic, profiler-based approach.

Comment: Though that definitely captures everything I want, it also captures a whole lot more, and wouldn't nicely fit into doxygen documentation. Very interesting nonetheless