# How can I profile a python script with many decorated methods?

Tags: python, cprofile, snakeviz

I'm using snakeviz/cProfile to view the profile data of a slow running python script.

However a lot of the longer running methods are wrapped with decorators and so I don't see the name of the function/method in the call but instead I see '`wrapped`' (ie the name of the function given within the decorator, see trivial case below)

```
def my_decorator(func):
    def wrapped(args, kwargs)
       # do thing
       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped
```

Is there a way to write my decorators to avoid this?  Or a parameter to cProfile, snakeviz I'm missing? Would `functools.wraps` help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python cProfile - decorated functions obscuring profile visualization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43813502/python-cprofile-decorated-functions-obscuring-profile-visualization)