# Pyglet App Running Slowly

Tags: python, pyglet

I have this application that is creating an alternate version of cookie clicker named pizza clicker. It's very basic but it's running really slowly and I can't get why.

```
import pyglet
window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen=True, caption="Click For Pizzas", resizable=True)
win_width = window.width
win_height = window.height
window.set_fullscreen(False)
window.set_size(win_width, win_height)
image_height = round(int(win_width/5)/1.4, 1)
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = pyglet.text.Label('Pizzas: 0', font_size=100, color=(0, 0, 0, 255),
                                   x=win_width//2, y=win_height - 100,
                                   anchor_x='left', anchor_y='top')
        self.points = 0
        self.number = 1
    def background(self):
        background_img = pyglet.resource.image('pizza_clicker.png')
        background_img.width = (win_width/5)*4
        background_img.height = win_height
        background_img.blit(int(win_width/5), 0, 0.5)
    def drawSidebar(self):
        width = int(win_width/5)
        height = int(win_height)
        sidebar_pattern = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern(color=(100, 100, 100, 100))
        sidebar = sidebar_pattern.create_image(width, height)
        sidebar.blit(0, 0)
        pizza = []
        images = ('pizza_1.png', 'pizza_5.png', 'pizza_5.png', 'pizza_5.png')
        for i in range (0, len(images)):
          divideby = 1.4 / (i + 1)
          pizza.append(pyglet.resource.image(images[i]))
          pizza[i].width = width
          pizza[i].height = round(width/1.4, 1)
          pizza[i].blit(0, window.height - (round(width/divideby, 1)))
    def getNumber(self, y):
        if y > window.height - int(image_height):
            self.number = 1
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*2):
            self.number = 5
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*3):
            self.number = 10
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*4):
            self.number = 20
    def addPoint(self):
       self.points += self.number
       self.label.text = 'Pizzas: %s' %self.points


@window.event
def on_mouse_press(x, y, buttons, modifiers):
    if buttons & pyglet.window.mouse.LEFT and x > win_width/5:
        main.addPoint()
    elif buttons & pyglet.window.mouse.LEFT and x < win_width/5:
        main.getNumber(y)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    main.background()
    main.label.draw()
    main.drawSidebar()

main = Main()

pyglet.app.run()
```

So the problem is that when I click on the right side of the window, it should add a point (or many) instantly but it lags for a few seconds. Also, just so nobody get confused, the code does work, but just slowly. What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On every `draw()` iteration, you're doing:

```
background_img = pyglet.resource.image('pizza_clicker.png')
```

This means you're loading in the same picture, from hard-drive, every render sequence. You're also doing a for loop over different pizza images where you also fetch them from hard drive:

```
for i in range (0, len(images)):
    divideby = 1.4 / (i + 1)
    pizza.append(pyglet.resource.image(images[i]))
```

I strongly suggest you read up on how resources are loaded in, and use a cProfiler analyzer.

A good example of how you could profile your code, is [here](https://thirld.com/blog/2014/11/30/visualizing-the-results-of-profiling-python-code/).
Since this is a external source, I'll include two SO's links as well that's about equally good (but not as potent or self explaining):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23164271/929999
- [Using cProfile results with KCacheGrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896032/using-cprofile-results-with-kcachegrind)

Here's a tl-dr version:

```
python -m cProfile -o profile_data.pyprof your_script.py
pyprof2calltree -i profile_data.pyprof -k
```

This should render a so called, "call tree", of all the executions your code did, how long they took and how much memory they used up. All the way from start to bottom of your application.

However, I strongly suggest you do **1 rendering sequence** and add a `exit(1)` after the first render. Just so you profile 1 run, not 60 per second.

Keywords to search for to get a hang of why your code is slow: Python, profiling, kcachegrind, cprofile, cprofiling, callstack.

### Spoiler alert

To solve the majority of your problems, move all I/O intensive operations (loading images, creating shapes etc) into the `__init__` call of your main class.

The end product would look something like this instead:

```
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = pyglet.text.Label('Pizzas: 0', font_size=100, color=(0, 0, 0, 255),
                                   x=win_width//2, y=win_height - 100,
                                   anchor_x='left', anchor_y='top')
        self.points = 0
        self.number = 1

        self.background_img = pyglet.resource.image('pizza_clicker.png')
        self.background_img.width = (win_width/5)*4
        self.background_img.height = win_height

        sidebar_pattern = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern(color=(100, 100, 100, 100))
        self.sidebar = sidebar_pattern.create_image(width, height)

        self.pizzas = []
        width = int(win_width/5)
        height = int(win_height)
        self.pizza_images = ('pizza_1.png', 'pizza_5.png', 'pizza_5.png', 'pizza_5.png')
        for i in range (0, len(pizza_images)):
            resource = pyglet.resource.image(pizza_images[i])
            resource.width = width
            resource.height = round(width/1.4, 1) # Not sure why you're using width here.. meh.. keeping it -yolo-
            self.pizzas.append(resource)

    def background(self):
        self.background_img.blit(int(win_width/5), 0, 0.5)

    def drawSidebar(self):
        width = int(win_width/5)
        height = int(win_height) # You're using win_height here, but window.height later. It's strange.
        self.sidebar.blit(0, 0)
        for i in range (0, len(self.pizza_images)):
            divideby = 1.4 / (i + 1)
            self.pizzas[i].blit(0, window.height - (round(width/divideby, 1)))

    def getNumber(self, y):
        if y > window.height - int(image_height):
            self.number = 1
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*2):
            self.number = 5
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*3):
            self.number = 10
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*4):
            self.number = 20

    def addPoint(self):
       self.points += self.number
       self.label.text = 'Pizzas: %s' %self.points
```

But why stop here, there's a lot of heavy use of `blit` here. Blit is fine for like one or two objects. But it quickly gets hard to track what and where you're "blitting" everything to. You're also doing a whole lof of division, addition and other sorts of calculations in loops and stuff.

Remember, loops are the devil in when it comes to rendering.
If you got a loop some where, you can almost certainly start looking there for performance issues *(anyone looking at this comment and going "pff he has no clue what he's saying".. Yea I know, but it's a good beginners tip)*.

I strongly suggest you put your images into [pyglet.sprite.Sprite()](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/modules/sprite.html) objects instead. They keep track of positions, rendering and most importantly, they support [batched rendering](http://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.3-maintenance/programming_guide/graphics.html#batched-rendering). That is your holy grail of the mother land! If anything's going to save you performance wise in pyglet.. well.. 3D rendering in general, it's batched rendering.

See, the graphic card was designed with one thing in mind.. Taking a HUGE mathematical equation and just swallow it whole. It's particularly good at taking a big fat stack of information and just shooting it to your screen. It's not as good at multiple commands. Meaning if you're sending many smaller packets back and fourth to the graphics card, it's going to perform no wear near optimum because of overhead and other things.

So, putting your images into sprites, and putting those sprites into batches, and not using any for loops and on-rendering resources loads..

This is what your code would look like:

```
class Main(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.label = pyglet.text.Label('Pizzas: 0', font_size=100, color=(0, 0, 0, 255),
                                   x=win_width//2, y=win_height - 100,
                                   anchor_x='left', anchor_y='top')
        self.points = 0
        self.number = 1

        self.background_layer = pyglet.graphics.OrderedGroup(0)
        self.foreground_layer = pyglet.graphics.OrderedGroup(1)
        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        self.background_img = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.resource.image('pizza_clicker.png'), batch=self.batch, group=self.background_layer)
        self.background_img.width = (win_width/5)*4
        self.background_img.height = win_height
        self.background.x = int(win_width/5)
        self.background.y = 0

        sidebar_pattern = pyglet.image.SolidColorImagePattern(color=(100, 100, 100, 100))
        self.sidebar = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(sidebar_pattern.create_image(width, height), batch=self.batch, group=self.background_layer)
        self.sidebar.x = 0
        self.sidebar.y = 0

        self.pizzas = []
        width = int(win_width/5)
        height = int(win_height)
        self.pizza_images = ('pizza_1.png', 'pizza_5.png', 'pizza_5.png', 'pizza_5.png')
        for i in range (0, len(pizza_images)):
            divideby = 1.4 / (i + 1)

            resource = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(pyglet.resource.image(pizza_images[i]), batch=self.batch, group=self.foreground_layer)
            resource.width = width
            resource.height = round(width/1.4, 1) # Not sure why you're using width here.. meh.. keeping it -yolo-
            resource.x = 0
            resource.y = window.height - (round(width/divideby, 1))

            self.pizzas.append(resource)

    def draw(self):
        # This is instead of doing:
        # - self.background.draw()
        # - self.sidebar.draw()
        # - self.pizzas[i].draw()
        self.batch.draw()
        self.label.draw() # You could put this in a batch as well :)

    def getNumber(self, y):
        if y > window.height - int(image_height):
            self.number = 1
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*2):
            self.number = 5
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*3):
            self.number = 10
        elif y > window.height - (int(image_height)*4):
            self.number = 20

    def addPoint(self):
        self.points += self.number
        self.label.text = 'Pizzas: %s' %self.points

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    main.draw()
```

Now, the code ain't perfect. But it will hopefully give you a sense of the heading you should be going towards. I haven't executed this code either, mainly because I don't have all the pizza images or the time. I might come back here and do so, and tidy up the (most likely) spelling errors I have.

Comment: the weird usage of width for height is due to proportions

Comment: @DiogoSCF I figured as much :) It was just a unintuative variable, and the double use of `win_height` vs `window.height`. Anyway, you know the variables way better than any of us can. I mainly hope the new code makes sense to you and that you can use some of it :)

Comment: It did work after a few modifications, and it is now much faster