# How to get the python import tree

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to find out how much different parts of my code base are used. How best to traverse the import tree and find out what imports what? Ideally the resulting data could tell me

- which objects are imported
- the files in which the imported objects are defined
- the files the objects are imported to

Note: One option is to run all the tests and profile using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4544784/5986907). However, tests are not even across the code base, with some areas having no tests, so this wouldn't be hugely representative.

Comment: Pyflakes, pylint or similar are useful tools for checking for unused imports (plus other things)

Comment: You can also just run your code with coverage (https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/), but that naturally won't be 100% accurate either.

Comment: Oh, and if it helps, you can also use `gc.get_objects()` to get a list of every single object known by the interpreter's garbage collector.

Answer (score 2):

Since all objects inherit from `object` you can get a list of all imported objects with:

```py
>>> object.__subclasses__()
[<class 'type'>, <class 'weakref'>, ...]
```

To find the module an object is first defined in use the `__module__` attribute:

```py
>>> type.__module__
'builtins'
```

A `dict` of all imported modules is available from the `sys` module. Using the module name as the key, the module object can be retrieved, the file name can then be obtained from the `__file__` attribute (for **most** modules).

```py
>>> import sys
>>> import csv
>>> csv_module = sys.modules['csv']
>>> csv_module.__file__
'...lib/python3.6/csv.py'
```

Note: Not all modules include the `__file__` attribute, notably the *builtins* module, be sure to use `hasattr(module, "__file__")` as a guard.

I'll leave how to put that together to get your tree up to you.

Comment: @joel, if you got how to do it, can you please share? Tim, it would help to expand your solution to provide the full method. Thanks in advance

Comment: Same request as above comment

Comment: All you need for a solution is in my answer. I don't have one built out, but this should be a fairly simple case of looping through each object in sub-classes.